# jQuery mobile - iOS - How to detect when the keyboard is opening?

Tags: jquery, ios, events, jquery-mobile, keyboard

I'm working on a jQuery mobile site and need to update my layout when the iOS keyboard is showing up or hiding.

Is there some event I can bind to? Doesn't necessarily have to be a JQM event, any other would also suffice.

Thanks for help!

Comment: It would be similar as other form elements have like blur and focus events...

Comment: Sounds to me that attaching the `resize` event would do, you can check innerWidth/innerHeight and change layout. Though I just read that Safari changes the innerHeight value without triggering `resize`. How odd.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Mobile does not offer an event for when the iOS keyboard is opened. You can [bind the `focus` and `onblur` events to handle this instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47798279/jquery-mobile-how-to-detect-if-mobile-virtual-keyboard-is-opened/47798742).